# How to change DatePicker dialog color for Android 5.0

Tags: android, dialog, styles, background-color

Is it possible to change the datepicker (and also the timepicker) color scheme for Android 5.0?

I've tried setting the accent colors, but this doesn't work (both with and without `android`):

```
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple</item>

<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/purple_tint</item>

<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/purple_tint</item>
```

From original:

[image: Original]

To something like this:

[image: Recolored]

Comment: What color is your color accent set to in your app theme styles

Comment: @Neil I've added the code that I've tryed to use for styling so far.

Answer (score 353, accepted):

The reason why Neil's suggestion results in a fullscreen `DatePicker` is the choice of parent theme:

```
<!-- Theme.AppCompat.Light is not a dialog theme -->
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="**Theme.AppCompat.Light**">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_500</item>
</style>
```

Moreover, if you go this route, you have to specify the theme while creating the `DatePickerDialog`:

```
// R.style.DialogTheme
new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}, 2015, 02, 26).show();
```

This, in my opinion, is not good. One should try to keep the styling out of java and inside styles.xml/themes.xml.

I do agree that Neil's suggestion, with a bit of change (changing the parent theme to say, `Theme.Material.Light.Dialog`) will get you the desired result. But, here's the other way:

On first inspection, we come across `datePickerStyle` which defines things such as: `headerBackground`(what you are trying to change), `dayOfWeekBackground`, and a few other text-colors and text-styles.

Overriding this attribute in your app's theme will not work. `DatePickerDialog` uses a separate theme assignable by the attribute `datePickerDialogTheme`. So, for our changes to take affect, we must **override `datePickerStyle` inside an overriden `datePickerDialogTheme`**.

Here we go:

Override `datePickerDialogTheme` inside your app's base theme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    ....
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Define `MyDatePickerDialogTheme`. The choice of parent theme will depend on what your app's base theme is: it could be either `Theme.Material.Dialog` or `Theme.Material.Light.Dialog`:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>
```

We have overridden `datePickerStyle` with the style `MyDatePickerStyle`. The choice of parent will once again depend on what your app's base theme is: either `Widget.Material.DatePicker` or `Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker`. Define it as per your requirements:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/chosen_header_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

Currently, we are only overriding `headerBackground` which by default is set to `?attr/colorAccent` (this is also why Neil suggestion works in changing the background). But there's quite a lot of customization possible:

```
dayOfWeekBackground
dayOfWeekTextAppearance
headerMonthTextAppearance
headerDayOfMonthTextAppearance
headerYearTextAppearance
headerSelectedTextColor
yearListItemTextAppearance
yearListSelectorColor
calendarTextColor
calendarSelectedTextColor
```

If you don't want this much control (customization), you don't need to override `datePickerStyle`. `colorAccent` controls most of the `DatePicker's` colors. So, overriding just `colorAccent` inside `MyDatePickerDialogTheme` should work:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/date_picker_accent</item>

    <!-- No need to override 'datePickerStyle' -->
    <!-- <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item> -->
</style>
```

Overriding `colorAccent` gives you the added benefit of changing `OK` & `CANCEL` text colors as well. Not bad.

This way you don't have to provide any styling information to `DatePickerDialog's` constructor. Everything has been wired properly:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
 }, 2015, 5, 22);

 dpd.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for a good and full description of how it works and how it had to be overriden in styles

Comment: Excellent explanation @Vikram how can we change ok, cancel text color ?

Comment: @Dipu Sorry about this late response - busy with work. I hope that you've found the solution by now. In case you haven't, I explain this process in detail over here: [How to explore styling in android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28683713/2558882).

Comment: @Vikram I found the solution same day after few R&D

Comment: @Vikram calendarSelectedTextColor not found.

Comment: Is it possible to be backward compatible for android < 21 the datePicker?

Comment: @RoCk Not sure what you mean, but I built a library to back port the Date & Time pickers from android version 23 to version 14. The project is hosted at: [https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker).

Comment: @Vikram - Sorry for vague question, I have an app that open datePicker for Birthdate. For Android not runnig Lollipop their date picker is not the same as shown above. How do I make that one, backward compatible?

Comment: @RoCk You will have to use a library project like the one I posted above. DatePicker as shown above is only available on API v21 & above. Android's own DatePicker also changed on API v23 - the months now scroll left-and-right, rather than up-and-down.

Comment: @Vikram Is it possible to increase the datepicker dialog width and height ? I have already tried: datePickerDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

Comment: Fantastic answer! I just wanted to add that I've found that `android:colorAccent` apparently does not cover the selection circle color, but plain `colorAccent` will cover *both* the selection color and the "OK"/"Cancel" button text. (Or you can different colors by using both!) This is with AndroidX Material 1.1.0 library and may well vary with different versions of the DatePicker.

Comment: @Vikram can we change the dialog shape ? For eg: the rounded corner radius

Answer (score 72):

Give this a try.

***The code***

```
new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}, 2015, 02, 26).show();
```

***The Style*** In your styles.xml file

**EDIT - Changed theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog as suggested**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_500</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes it's purple, but also full screen :) but maybe if I put it inside a fragment it will be contained. Any suggestions before I start playing around with it again?

Comment: I'll see if I can find a more appropriate solution that doesn't cause it to go full screen

Comment: Just use `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"` instead of `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

Comment: @Neil thanks for the answer, pointed me in the right direction and this is properly the quickest solution but I was looking for an all style/theme approach :)

Comment: Not working on android 6, it is full screen and color is not changed

Answer (score 27):

Create a new style

```
<!-- Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog -->
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_500</item>
</style>
```

Java code:

The parent theme is the key here. 
Choose your colorAccent

```
DatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,R.style.DialogTheme,this,now.get(Calendar.YEAR),now.get(Calendar.MONTH),now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

try this, work for me

Put the two options, `colorAccent` and `android:colorAccent`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   ....
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

<!-- Put the two options, colorAccent and android:colorAccent. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't require v24 apis and above 

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention, you can also use the default a theme like `android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog` instead.

```
new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    //DO SOMETHING
    }
}, 2015, 02, 26).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have create theme just write it in your dialog creation object

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

follow this it will give you all type date picker style
it's really work

http://www.android-examples.com/change-datepickerdialog-theme-in-android-using-dialogfragment/

Comment: Works like Gem, bro!

Comment: AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT deprecated.. not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that time picker buttons have not been seen in the screen for API 24 in android. (API 21+)
it is solved by

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary2</item></style>

<style name="Theme" parent="BBaseTheme">
         <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppThemeDatePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/select2</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/select2</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/select2</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Changing Year list item text color (SPECIFIC FOR ANDROID 5.0)**

Just set certain text color in your date picker dialog style. For some reason setting flag `yearListItemTextAppearance` doesn't reflect any change on year list.

```
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin, 2021**

```
// set date as button text if pressed
btnDate.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

    val dpd = DatePickerDialog(
        this,
        { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            val selectDate = Calendar.getInstance()
            selectDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            selectDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            selectDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            var formatDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
            val date = formatDate.format(selectDate.time)
            Toast.makeText(this, date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            btnDate.text = date
        }, 1990, 6, 6
    )

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = calendar[Calendar.YEAR]
    val month = calendar[Calendar.MONTH]
    val day = calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
    dpd.datePicker.minDate = GregorianCalendar(year - 90, month, day, 0, 0).timeInMillis
    dpd.datePicker.maxDate = GregorianCalendar(year - 10, month, day, 0, 0).timeInMillis
    dpd.show()
})
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- This is main Theme Style for your application! -->
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#A500FF</item>
</style>
```

[image]