# Android DatePicker apply theme as Per Image

Tags: android, datepicker

I need to apply theme to DatePicker [image: LikeThis]
i get some links But, this  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0)  is for Android 5 But i need it using android 4.4.2

Please Help me to solve it

Thanks,

Comment: try to use some material library for it

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this design is coming under material only. I think you can also do this by using this  [datetimepicker library](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker)

[image]