# TimePickerDialog unable to change default colors

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker

I have a TimePickerDialog with a Holo Light theme. I want to change the default light blue line color that encloses the selected value and also change the color of the selected value including AM/PM. I have tried to use `textColorPrimary` by creating a custom theme in `styles.xml`but that changes the color of all the numbers.

What are the properties that I should change for the light blue line, the selected value color, change the OK and cancel button color and also get a rounded corner dialog box.

Here is a screenshot of the dialog with textColorPrimary set to RED

[image]

Comment: change accent color in style

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it is accomplished:

```
TimePicker time_picker; //Instantiated in onCreate()
Resources system;

private void set_timepicker_text_colour(){
    system = Resources.getSystem();
    int hour_numberpicker_id = system.getIdentifier("hour", "id", "android");
    int minute_numberpicker_id = system.getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android");
    int ampm_numberpicker_id = system.getIdentifier("amPm", "id", "android");

    NumberPicker hour_numberpicker = (NumberPicker) time_picker.findViewById(hour_numberpicker_id);
    NumberPicker minute_numberpicker = (NumberPicker) time_picker.findViewById(minute_numberpicker_id);
    NumberPicker ampm_numberpicker = (NumberPicker) time_picker.findViewById(ampm_numberpicker_id);

    set_numberpicker_text_colour(hour_numberpicker);
    set_numberpicker_text_colour(minute_numberpicker);
    set_numberpicker_text_colour(ampm_numberpicker);
}

private void set_numberpicker_text_colour(NumberPicker number_picker){
    final int count = number_picker.getChildCount();
    final int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.text);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = number_picker.getChildAt(i);

        try{
            Field wheelpaint_field = number_picker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
            wheelpaint_field.setAccessible(true);

            ((Paint)wheelpaint_field.get(number_picker)).setColor(color);
            ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
             number_picker.invalidate();
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the above code, the color is only set for the beginning. What I want is every time a value passes through the two light blue while scrolling; it should become red and then back to black color if it goes out the two light blue lines.