# android:headerBackground having no effect

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently working on creating a custom theme for a datePicker and I'm having some difficulty with setting the headerBackground and the circle around the selected date separately. I've set my theme up like this:

```
<style name="State0DatePickerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/state0Dark</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/state0Primary</item>
</style>
```

App theme looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="State0BaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/state0Primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/state0Dark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/state0Primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/state0Primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And last but not least, State0BaseTheme looks like this:

```
<style name="State0BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/state0Primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/state0Dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/state0Primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/state0Primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I had thought that overriding colorAccent, and setting headerBackground would work just fine, but I guess not? Here's what it looks like with all these styles:

[image]

If I set android:headerBackground in the xml of the datePicker, everything works great. However, I want to be able to change the theme for all screens of the app based on user input. Thoughts as to why this isn't working?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/5873832

Answer (score 0):

I read the link posted by @DasserBasyouni and found that making the parent of my datePickerTheme `@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker` and setting `android:datePickerStyle` to `@style/State0DatePickerTheme` in `State0BaseTheme` worked perfectly