# Android DatePicker Selector Color

Tags: java, android, xml, datepicker

So, this question is kind of an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420721/androidheaderbackground-having-no-effect?), I solved the issue with the `headerBackground` but I realised that I had manually set the theme of my `DatePicker` in my layout using `android:theme="@style/State0DatePickerTheme`. But when I removed that line from my XML, the day selector just turned back to white (my accent colour defined in my base theme). Any thoughts on why this is, or how to fix it?

For my purposes, I need to have the theme for `DatePicker` set in my styles.xml with `android:datePickerStyle` because I'm setting my theme dynamically in my `onCreate()` and I can't change the theme of the datePicker in java (at least not that I'm aware of).

Comment: you can use the alternate library here is link     
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out how to fix it, I simply created a new theme (which I called `State0HistoryTheme`) and then made its parent `State0BaseTheme` and applied that theme to my entire activity in my `onCreate()` using `setTheme()`

This is what my `State0HistoryTheme` looks like for those curious:

```
<style name="State0HistoryTheme" parent="State0BaseTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/state0Dark</item>
</style>
```

This was able to override the `colorAccent` that I had set in `State0BaseTheme`