# How to change font in DatePickerDialog android

Tags: java, android, fonts, datepicker

I want to change font in DatePickerDialog ,but I have no idea to set it

How to change font in DatePickerDialog android? 
thanks!

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
    getContext(), this, startYear, starthMonth, startDay);
```

Comment: Add a custom *style* for your datepicker and add it in the layout.

Comment: use this answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/4571925

Comment: this link may help you http://androiddatepicker.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TextView titleTextView = (TextView) datePickerDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
titleTextView.setText("Nilesh Rathod");
titleTextView.setTextSize(20);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BLACKROSE.TTF");
titleTextView.setTypeface(tf);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

and this also

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout layout = layout1.getChildAt(0);

// day
LinearLayout day = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(0);
setNumberPicker(day);

// month
LinearLayout month = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(1);
setNumberPicker(month);

// year
LinearLayout year = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(2);
setNumberPicker(year);
```

**now change type using this method**

```
private void setNumberPicker(LinearLayout ll) {
    ((ImageButton) ll.getChildAt(0)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus_button);
    ((ImageButton) ll.getChildAt(2)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.minus_button);

    EditText et = (EditText) ll.getChildAt(1);
    et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),   "fonts/BLACKROSE.TTF");
    et.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

Comment: in line `LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);` cannot call `getChildAt(0)`

Comment: @ARR.s just add this DatePickerDialog in your xml layout

Comment: @ARR.s **After taking a look at the source, the Datepicker widget holds 3 NumberPicker widgets (for day, month, year)which in turn hold a TextView. So you are going have to set the Typeface for the TextView inside the NumberPickers inside the DatePicker.

I think you'll have to get the source for both NumberPicker and DatePicker and modify the source to achieve this, easier said than done I'm afraid.**