# How to Change the DatePickerDialog's Background Color from default White?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am trying to set the Dark Theme Style for the `DatePickerDialog` in Android. As per [Vikram's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0/28738461), I don't want to set style in `DatePickerDilog's` Constructor.

I set the following styles & it's set but doesn't apply to OK & Cancel button's panel in Portrait mode. However, it works in Landscape!!:

My v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark.NoActionBar">
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
     <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryColorDark_dark</item>
     <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePicker_Theme_Dark</item>
</style>
<!--Dark DatePicker Theme & style-->
<style name="DatePicker_Theme_Dark" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePicker_Dark</item>
</style>
<style name="DatePicker_Dark" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primaryColor_dark</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorAccent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textPrimaryColor_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textSecondaryColor_dark</item>
</style>
```

My styles.xml:

```
<!-- Dark Application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/backgroundColor_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textSecondaryColor_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textPrimaryColor_dark</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePicker_Dark</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePicker_Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primaryColor_dark</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorAccent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textPrimaryColor_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textSecondaryColor_dark</item>
</style>
```

In my .java file, I am getting the new instance of the `DatePickerDialog` as follows:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day){
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(@NonNull DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
          onDateSet(view, year, month, dayOfMonth);
          dismiss();
    }
 };
```

Snapshot:
[image: DatePicker]

Your Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: share your java file.

Answer (score 1):

`DatePicker` color is the choice of parent theme.

```
<!-- Theme.AppCompat.Light is not a dialog theme -->
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="**Theme.AppCompat.Light**">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

and in `DatePickerDialog()` use above theme.

```
new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}, 2015, 02, 26).show();
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to pass style in the DatePickerDialog's Constructor. However, I edited my question to brief all my styles.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I found to change color of Button Bar toolbar is to pass @StyleRes

```
AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL
AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK
AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
```

when instantiating DatePickerDialog. Furthermore changing theme attributes it might accept custom color but I didn't check that out. For me it was enough just to change it to @color/colorPrimary like bellow example. Hope this helps.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, dateSetListener, year,month,day);
```