# Set DatePicker material style

Tags: android, material-design

In my app I can see this type DatePickler

[image]

But I want to use this type style,

[image]

Do not take into account the color in the photos, I just need to change the shape.

In this Material web can find more pictures type of DatePickler that I need:

https://material.io/guidelines/components/pickers.html#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Datepicker dialog color for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/5110595)

Comment: @Hemant Parmar No, I say in my question that I not want to change the color. This link is for change the color.

Comment: ok you mean wants to change  style of view ? right ?

Comment: not duplicate...he is asking diffrent question

Comment: @Hemant Parmar Yes, style. Please note that 2 pictures that I put have different styles.

Comment: @user2983041 here is the complete solution have look [this](http://www.zoftino.com/android-datepicker-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link.

http://www.android-examples.com/change-datepickerdialog-theme-in-android-using-dialogfragment/

**DialogFragment For DatePicker:**

```
public static class DatePickerDialogTheme extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

     @Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


//for DatePicker with diffrent style

 DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
 AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,year,month,day);



     return datepickerdialog;
     }

     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){

     TextView textview = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     textview.setText(day + ":" + (month+1) + ":" + year);

     }
     }
```

**Open DatePicker on Button Click:**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 DialogFragment dialogfragment = new DatePickerDialogTheme();

 dialogfragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Theme");

 }
 });
```

Code is same as you can see on that link

Hope this will help you...