# Change header background of DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

I've got a `DatePickerDialog` of which I would like to change the background color of the header. I've made it so that the default background of the whole application is white but now, because of the white text in the header of the `Dialog` it's not visible and looks very weird.
[image]

I've tried to use many other answers from SO but no luck there, this is the style I have set up in my styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Much appreciated!

Edit: For now, since I don't use many layouts in this app, I've fixed it by setting the background for each element to white manually. A fix would still be nice...

Comment: Did you try to set `colorControlNormal` and `colorControlActivated`?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0

Comment: @K.Dexter I've tried the answers in there but no luck.

Comment: @Lamorak Tried now but no luck.

Comment: you did overwrite datePickerDialogTheme inside your app's base theme?

Comment: @K.Dexter yeah and still no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Put it inside style.xml file
<style name="yourCustomStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/yellow</item>
        .. other
    </style>

//After replace below code to your code 

new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.yourCustomStyle, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
    {

    }
}, 2015, 02, 26).show();
```

Comment: That made the datepicker fullscreen and still with a white header background.

Comment: Yes, like this `DatePickerDialog datepickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme ,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {`

Comment: Your date picker is inside xml file or not  . if  yes then use below code .                      
  <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/start_date_text"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        style="@style/yourCustomStyle" />  If no then inside  Your DialogTheme style item color changed

Comment: I generate it in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Put it in your style.xml file
 <style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/quicksand_regular</item>
    </style>


//after below code put in your view  onclickListner 

public void Datepiker()
{
    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,R.style.datepicker,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    txt_PickupDate_val.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + monthOfYear  + "-" + year);

                  //  txt_PickupDate_val.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what my code looks like now and it's not working.