# How fix color bottom panel DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

Color bottom panel DatePickerDialog white color.

Need set custom color

my style

```
    <style name="DefaultTheme.DatePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:headerBackground">#FF00C853</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="android:calendarTextColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    </style>
```

and use

```
<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DefaultTheme.DatePicker</item>
```

[now so](http://prntscr.com/nm7qu8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the DatePickerDialog bottom panel color, refer to this link:

[Change Datepicker dialog color for Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0/29014475#29014475)

The three steps you need to do, in order, are:

1. )  Override datePickerDialogTheme inside your app's base theme:

   `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
           <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
       </style>`

2.)  Override colorAccent inside MyDatePickerDialogTheme

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/date_picker_accent</item>

    <!-- No need to override 'datePickerStyle' -->
    <!-- <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item> -->
</style>
```

3.) Call it this way

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
 }, 2015, 5, 22);

 dpd.show();
```

Comment: I watched this answer but never found how to change exactly the bottom panel

Comment: Updated answer here