# How to change background color of the button in DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datepicker, styles, android-alertdialog

In my fragment I create a `DatepickerDialog`. Now  I want to change the background color of the buttons programmatically. How can I do that?

Comment: what buttons are you talking about. are you looking for something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0/28738461?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Button from Dialog and modify it attributes using `getButton()`. See the example below. Get the button after calling `.show()`, otherwise it will give a `null`.

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int  mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ConstarintsActivity.this,
                (view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
        datePickerDialog.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```