# Changing day color in a Calendarview

Tags: android

I want to change if it is possible, only the background color/tint of all Sundays of the current month

like this pic, thank you for your time

[image]

Comment: You can use [use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()) documentation should help you out. Using the getFirstDayofWeek() should get your Sunday and then using [setWeekDayTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setWeekDayTextAppearance(int)) I'm assuming would allow you to change it. I haven't personally used CalendarView before but the documentation looks pretty straightforward.