# Date picker Dialog shows only one date

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datepickerdialog

[image]

I am trying to implement the date picker dialog but the dialog appears with just a single date and show rest of the date as blank what could be the reason?

Comment: Show the code bro

Comment: change the theme of date picker dialog. its because of your application theme.

Comment: you can custom color of data picker dialog

Comment: It looks like a Theme issue, just change the app theme or make a custom theme for the Date picker dialog and apply it on code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a Theme issue. The selected date is visible because of the contrast in text color and circle color. You can refer this link for understanding the anatomy of the Date Picker theme by the Material design guideline.

https://material.io/components/date-pickers#theming

Refer this answer for understanding which colors to use.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/4491971

You can use these attributes to change the colors via style

```
dayOfWeekBackground
dayOfWeekTextAppearance
headerMonthTextAppearance
headerDayOfMonthTextAppearance
headerYearTextAppearance
headerSelectedTextColor
yearListItemTextAppearance
yearListSelectorColor
calendarTextColor
calendarSelectedTextColor
```

If you share the current style and the code snippet, we can refine the answer more.