# How to change Xamarin DatePicker popup header and Background to White and also Font Color to Gray

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to give custom look and feel to the datePicker popup. But I could not find any direct fields to change the header Background and Font Color of text shown in popup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBXqR.png)

Comment: Because if you want to change that you need to do it natively for the platform, and its based of the theme of your application

Comment: @FreakyAli, Thanks For your Response. Do you have any reference to change the Theme only for a specific control, not for the overall application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/7462031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using below code inside styles.xml in Android Project.

```
    <resources>
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!--header background-->
    <item name="colorAccent">#fff</item>
    <!--header textcolor-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#808080</item>
    <!--body background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#fff</item>
    <!--selected day-->
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#4B6043</item>
    <!--days of the month-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#808080</item>
    <!--days of the week-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#808080</item>
    <!--cancel&ok-->
    <item name="android:textColor">#808080</item>
</style>
```

[image: Customized Xamarin Forms Date Picker]