# Change CalendarView weekday name's layout of DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker, calendarview

I'm trying to customize a CalendarView of the DatePicker from DatePickerDialog. I already changed DatePickerDialog's background and button label color style, thanks to [excellent Vikram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523707/how-to-explore-styling-in-android/28683713#28683713). Now I want to change layout of weekday name abbreviation inside CalendarView. Change their background color and text color.

Looking inside styles_materials.xml file from AndroidSDK folder values, this style is there:

```
<style name="Widget.Material.Light.CalendarView" parent="Widget.CalendarView">
    <item name="selectedWeekBackgroundColor">#330066ff</item>
    <item name="focusedMonthDateColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="unfocusedMonthDateColor">#7F08002B</item>
    <item name="weekNumberColor">#7F080021</item>
    <item name="weekSeparatorLineColor">#7F08002A</item>
    <item name="weekDayTextAppearance">@style/TextApp earance.Material.CalendarViewWeekDayView</item>
    <item name="calendarViewMode">material</item>
</style>
```

I've overrided and applied my custom style in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/CustomDatePickerStyle</item> 
</style>

<style name="CustomDatePickerCalendarView" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.CalendarView">
        <item name="android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor">@color/viking</item>
        <item name="android:focusedMonthDateColor">@color/viking</item>
        <item name="android:unfocusedMonthDateColor">@color/viking</item>
        <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/viking</item>
        <item name="android:weekSeparatorLineColor">@color/viking</item>
    </style>
```

I've made a test setting most of the parameters with the same color. But it didn't work. Why the style cannot be applied?

EDIT:

To be more clear, I want to change the hightlighted part:
[image]